# Why doesn't html:form struts tag trigger focus event?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, struts-1

The following html code:

```
<html:form action="myAction" focus="code">
    <html:text styleId="inputCode" property="code" />
</html>
```

generates the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!--
        var focusControl = document.forms["MyForm"].elements["code"];

        if (focusControl != null && focusControl.type != "hidden" 
              && !focusControl.disabled && focusControl.style.display != "none") {
            focusControl.focus();
        }
    // -->
</script>
```

which should focus the code input text, but it isn't. I have tried writting that exactly same javascript code in my ready function and that way it works perfectly. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?